# Python: error problems to import module matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime-error

This afternoon after installing progressbar I have this problem importing matplolib:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 772, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 690, in rc_params
    fname = matplotlib_fname()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 602, in matplotlib_fname
    fname = os.path.join(get_configdir(), 'matplotlibrc')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 253, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 475, in _get_configdir
    raise RuntimeError("'%s' is not a writable dir; you must set %s/.matplotlib to be a writable dir.  You can also set environment variable MPLCONFIGDIR to any writable directory where you want matplotlib data stored "% (h, h))
RuntimeError: 'C:\Users\ALEM' is not a writable dir; you must set C:\Users\ALEM/.matplotlib to be a writable dir.  You can also set environment variable MPLCONFIGDIR to any writable directory where you want matplotlib data stored
```

I had tried to reinstall matplolib and python 27 several times on my windows 7 64 bit, but I have always the same error.

The Error message says:

> please run the chkdsk utility

But I don't understand where is this utility and how I can run it.

Comment: did you try the suggestion in the error message?  "you must set C:\Users\ALEM/.matplotlib to be a writable dir.  You can also set environment variable MPLCONFIGDIR to any writable directory where you want matplotlib data stored"

Comment: the Error message say: please run te chkdsk utlity. But i didn't understand where is this utily and how i can run. Thanks for help

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting that error.  It's not in the stacktrace.  I would start with the hint in the stacktrace and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: i did in the way to resinstall everything from zero, but Thanks David S for your help. It's always appreciate

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if I was much help, but always happy to try!  Best of luck!